# can't ping/ssh/http(s) request to another vm(kvm)

Tags: networking, debian, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-share

0

I have problem with KVM in Debian, I build two VM machines (windows and Debian VM). I want this VM machines to be accessible by each other
I googled it and I know I need to build a bridge and I did it but I'm getting this error after I restart network service

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

in debian vm (network interface)

```
auto br-0be2471c19a5
iface br-0be2471c19a5 inet static
       address 172.18.0.1
       broadcast 172.18.255.255
       netmask 255.255.0.0
       gateway 172.18.0.1
       bridge_ports ens3
       bridge_stp off
       bridge_waitport 0
       bridge_fd 0
```

ifconfig results

```
ifconfig
br-0be2471c19a5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:33ff:fee3:2081  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:33:e3:20:81  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1  bytes 28 (28.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34  bytes 4356 (4.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-2eb60ee5fb72: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:c8ff:fe82:412b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:c8:82:41:2b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 33  bytes 4275 (4.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:b4:55:de:69  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 185.50.39.205  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 185.50.39.255
        ether 52:54:00:3f:56:e5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 744  bytes 58527 (57.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 248  bytes 40338 (39.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 156 (156.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 156 (156.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth173e94b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::f410:42ff:fe70:b4b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f6:10:42:70:0b:4b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29  bytes 3495 (3.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth6ec8100: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::20c8:d6ff:fea2:3752  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 22:c8:d6:a2:37:52  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1493  bytes 112957 (110.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1094  bytes 127802 (124.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth712d17e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::28b0:9aff:fece:8c8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2a:b0:9a:ce:08:c8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 44  bytes 5806 (5.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth7b75adc: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::68df:e6ff:fe77:998  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 6a:df:e6:77:09:98  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48  bytes 6094 (5.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethd55222a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::98e5:5eff:fe48:9127  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9a:e5:5e:48:91:27  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1063  bytes 123859 (120.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1524  bytes 116900 (114.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

windows ipconfig

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3992:5858:6140:3981%2
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 185.50.39.165
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 185.50.39.254

Tunnel adapter isatap.{00DC3EBC-F6C1-495D-8224-9B5216066F6A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:2851:782c:2499:261c:46cd:d85a
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2499:261c:46cd:d85a%13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

Comment: it is very unclear what exactly you are trying to do. also, can u post windows's ipconfig message

Comment: @AntonStafeyev sorry for that typo , i updated post please check it

Comment: @AntonStafeyev i want can be ping/ssh/http request from windows server to debian but i cant, something block my request
ping (moviom.com or server ip  185.50.39.205) 
Pinging moviom.com [185.50.39.205] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 185.50.39.165: Destination host unreachable.
Ping statistics for 185.50.39.205:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Comment: Did you assign this IP addresses manually?

Comment: yes my server have static ip and i added this ip manualy

Comment: Where did you get this IP addresses from? who gave them to you?

Comment: I bought this ip from datacenter, I've heard for build bridge i most set an static ip

Comment: So your equipment is in datacenter?

Comment: yes is it this is an dedicated server

Comment: if it is a dedicated server in a data center then call management and they will set your network up. Or you can schedule a visit to a server and check your physical connection.